# Object not found after installing and loading package

Tags: r

I've thrown together a bunch of my utility functions into a package. However, I can't seem to access them after I've installed the package. I get errors of the form `Error: object 'function_name' not found`

1. Building the package, there are no error messages
2. Installing the package from source, there are no error messages
3. Loading the package, there are no error messages (library() nor require())
4. The package documentation is accessible once loaded
5. I'm using roxygen2 to generate documentation and the namespace

Any thoughts?

Comment: Did you create a NAMESPACE and export all the functions you want to make available?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you use a NAMESPACE and forgot to add the object in question?

If you're using roxygen2, have you remembered to add `#' @export function_name` to the functions you want included in the namespace?

Comment: There is a file called NAMESPACE but I didn't create it myself. It's empty - what's supposed to be in it?

Comment: I think you some light reading in the most excellent "Writing R Extensions" manual ahead of you :)   There are also a few dozen posts here in the "[r] NAMESPACE" search results.  It'll all be crystal-clear in twenty minutes but you have to do that legwork.

Comment: Is there a way to tell it to just export everything, in one line? Without having to write each individual function out?

Comment: Found it. Thanks - `exportPattern("^[^\\.]")`

Comment: Your answer led me to what I was looking for, but my problem was more specific than I originally thought because roxygen2 was generating the namespace for me automatically and I wasn't aware that I needed to specify export names for packaging. I've updated your answer to reflect that peculiarity of my situation.

Comment: Yup, that would do the trick -- or manually edit the NAMESPACE file (though the evil rozygen2 witch may overwrite that change).

Comment: Roxygen2 shouldn't override the namespace if you don't have any namespace directives. But I really recommend manually exporting the functions you want. Its much better developemet practice.

Comment: Yes, roxygen2 does overwrite the namespace when you write it manually. hadley, I'm assuming that's by design - now it's a habit. But, it did overwrite my namespace even though I had no @export calls (considering I didn't know about them until I started searching for stuff on namespace + roxygen)

Comment: Found this problem with the [climstats](http://r-forge.r-project.org/projects/climstats/) package. The package had an empty NAMESPACE. Thanks for the solution, guys.

Answer (score 3):

If the function name is not exported, you may need to use ":::"

```
pkgname:::function_name
```

I believe that CRAN now requires a NAMESPACE, and I think  R 2.14.x may even require them.

Comment: If an R 2.14 package does not have a NAMESPACE then the R 2.14 build of the package will add a NAMESPACE that exports all objects and imports everything listed in Imports or Depends.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck interesting. I wonder if it wouldn't be prudent for R to look at the NAMESPACE file and see if it actually contains anything. I had an empty NAMESPACE, and that's where my problem came in.

Answer (score 0):

The same problem for me, you need to change NAMESPACE file. sometime NAMESPACE's content looks like this:

`# Generated by roxygen2: do not edit by hand`

But you need to change it *by hand*, like this:

```
# Generated by roxygen2: do not edit by hand 
export("function_name1", "function_name2")
```

OR use `exportPattern("^[^\\.]")` to export all function.